# Bluetooth BLE beacon in cordova

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

First, i'm pretty new to the BLE beacon concept. I have an idea but don't know if it's possible.

1. I have an mobile app ( cordova ) where users are logged in. My idea is, when the user is close to my physical location, I want to send them a push notification to check in.

Is i posible to get the users bluetooth UUID from the app and save it to their profile, and then have a raspberry pi scanning for theies UUIDs, and when a "new" device is close and the UUID is know I can sent out a push?

Do anyone know if this can work, and is stable enough?

I have research a little, but can't find a cordova plugin to get the mobile app device own UUID for saving to the user profile, anyone know how to get that, if it is possible?

2. Another way of duing what i want, is to search for a beacon from the users device when it's near a beacon, but can that be done in the background without opening the app?

I have looked at this cordova plugin https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle and https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central  but can't see how to get the devices own UUID.

Comment: Your concept has the phone advertise a beacon identifier from the background and have a Raspberry Pi detect it.  Advertising from the background is possible on Android but not iOS using conventional beacon formats.  A more workable approach is to have the mobile app scan for beacons from the background.  You can replace the Raspberry Pi with a beacon transmitter then make the app send a local notification when the beacon is detected.

Comment: Thanks alot for you input... But can my app connect / find a beacon in the background and trigger a local notification, even if the app is "hard" closed by the user? is that not a problem in both ios and android?

Comment: This works well on iOS.  On Android it can also work, but you may need to have the user whitelist your app in settings to exclude it from background power restrictions on devices made by Chinese OEMs.